# How to invoke flash messages defined in locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a message called `my_message` in `config/locales/post.en.yml` as follow:

```
en:
  post:
    show:
      my_message: "Post was successfully saved. And Boom!"
```

How do I call this :my_message for a flash in a controller's method?

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
     flash[:error] = my_message
  end
end
```

Comment: Try `t('post.show.my_message')`. [Rails Guides on Looking up translations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations).

Comment: Make that an answer, I'll delete mine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In application controller rails 4 send your locale in parameters so that it get it in contoller by params[:locale]

```
 before_action :set_locale  

 def set_locale  
   I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
 end
```

Then

`flash[:error] = t('post.show.my_message')`

Answer (score 2):

Try the `I18n.t` helper

```
flash[:error] = t('.my_message')
```

Or, if that doesn't work, use full path:

```
flash[:error] = t('post.show.my_message')
```